# Clone a linked list with next and random pointer

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

You are given a Doubly-Linked List with one pointer of each node pointing to the next node just like in a Singly-Linked list. The second pointer however CAN point to ANY arbitrary node in the list, not just the previous node. Now write a program/algorithm in O(n) time to duplicate this list.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking "Will someone does this for me?"

Comment: I hate to say that StackOverflow is not for homework help, but it's not for homework help :(

Comment: While this is a neat problem, StackOverflow isn't a "please do my homework for me" site.

Comment: This is an assignment intended to teach algorithm analysis and design and you would not learn this from any provided answer. I would approach this the same way I would a puzzle: put together the pieces for which you know the order and put the unknowns off to the side for later. This approach may not meet O(N), but it will put you in a position where you can ask a question that should be answered.

Comment: Based on what you had before your last edit (when you had `arbit`), this isn't a _doubly linked_ list in the classic sense. It's a _singly linked_ list with an extra pointer. That said, the real problem is to translate the `arbit` pointer in a _new_ list element so that it points to the correct new element rather than still referring to the element in the _old_ list. AFAICT, this translation will take longer than O(n), quite possibly O(n^2). It might help to add more information as to exactly what is allowed as far as intermediate lists, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important that you try to solve such puzzles on your own -- it's a vital part of learning to be a coder. But I can give you a couple of hints.

First, can you duplicate the nodes and their `next` pointers? That should be easy.

After you've done that, can you see the difficulty in duplicating the connections of the `other` pointers? Can you imagine an additional memory structure that would help you to do it in O(n)?

Finally, imagine that in addition to the `next` and `other` pointers, each node has a `spare` pointer, pointing to nothing in particular, which you are allowed to modify. Would that be enough to let you solve the problem? And since that pointer doesn't exist, can you think of a way to improvise it?